# Geometry Question on the Circumcentre, Incentre and Centroid of a Triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, centroid

## Question

If there is a triangle $ABC$ where its circumcentre, incentre and centroid are named $O, I, G$ respectively, $AB=c$, $BC=a$, $CA=b$, and the radii of the circumcircle and incircle of the triangle are $R$ and $r$ respectively, prove that

$$R^2-OG^2\ge4(r^2-IG^2)$$

## Working

After thinking about this question for a little, as it is from a course, I watched the explanation. It used a theorem (of which I unfortunately forgot its name) where it states that

> If $G$ is the centroid of a triangle, and $P$ is any other point inside the triangle not on the circumference, $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2=\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)+3PG^2$.

So the course teacher said that we should have

\begin{align}
OA^2+OB^2+OC^2&=\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)+3OG^2\\
R^2+R^2+R^2&=\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)+3OG^2\\
3R^2-3OG^2&=\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)\\
R^2-OG^2&=\frac19(a^2+b^2+c^2)
\end{align}

And also that

\begin{align}
IA^2+IB^2+IC^2&=\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)+3IG^2
\end{align}

We can drop a perpendicular from the incircle of $ABC$ so that $IM\perp AB$ at $M$, so $IA^2=r^2+AM^2$ by Pythagoras, and then $IA^2=r^2+(P-a)^2$, where $P$ is the semi-perimeter of the triangle. By the same logic, $IB^2=r^2+(P-b)^2$ and $IC^2=r^2+(P-c)^2$, so

\begin{align}
IA^2+IB^2+IC^2&=\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)+3IG^2\\
3r^2+(P-a)^2+(P-b)^2+(P-c)^2&=\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)+3IG^2\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
r^2-IG^2&=\frac13\left[\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(P-a)^2-(P-b)^2-(P-c)^2\right]\\
&=\frac19\left[(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(P-a)^2-(P-b)^2-(P-c)^2\right]\\
&=\frac19\left[a^2+b^2+c^2-P^2-a^2+2aP-P^2-b^2+2bP-P^2-c^2+2cP\right]\\
&=\frac19\left[-3P^2+2aP+2bP+2cP\right]\\
&=-\frac13P^2+\frac19\left[a(a+b+c)+b(a+b+c)+c(a+b+c)\right]\\
&=-\frac13(a+b+c)^2\cdot\frac14+\frac19(a+b+c)^2\\
&=\left(\frac19-\frac1{12}\right)(a+b+c)^2\\
r^2-IG^2&=\frac1{36}(a+b+c)^2\\
4(r^2-IG^2)&=\frac19(a+b+c)^2
\end{align}

But this is a contradiction, as $a,b,c$ are all positive, so we have proved that

$$R^2-OG^2\le 4(r^2-IG^2)$$

Can anyone please tell me where the course teacher got it wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @ Cheese Cake If I am not mistaken, the line $$r^2-IG^2=\frac{1}{36}(a+b+c)^2$$ cannot be deduced from the line above it.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Hi, I've added more steps in the working. Could you please specify where the mistake(s) are?

Comment: @LiKwokKeung I believe the working checks out. Have you tried a geometrical construction? I've been following this post while working on that.

Comment: @ Cheese Cake It should come to:
$$r^2-IG^2=\frac{1}{3}\left[ \frac{1}{3}\left(a^2+b^2+c^2 \right)-3P^2+2(a+b+c)P-\left(a^2+b^2+c^2 \right)\right]=\frac{1}{3}\left[ \frac{1}{4}(a+b+c)^2-\frac{2}{3}\left(a^2+b^2+c^2 \right) \right]$$

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Thank you very much! So should I now use the fact that $(a+b+c)^2\ge a^2+b^2+c^2$ where $a,b,c >0$?

Comment: @CheeseCake I  expand $(a+b+c)^2$ and use $2ab \leq a^2+b^2, \cdots$ to obtain the inequality needed.

Comment: @Goku I just follow the working of Cheese Cake. I don't know how to do it geometrically.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung it is possible, actually, using an equilateral triangle, if you want to.

Comment: @Goku Thank you very much. I will see if I can do it geometrically.